# How can I type only references in my article?

Tags: bibliographies

Question: I am writing a review paper in which I want to type only references separately. How can I do this?

Please guide me

My given MWE contains few references in the form of Bibliography.bib as under .

```
@article{eringen1964simple,
  title={Simple microfluids},
  author={Eringen, A Cemal},
  journal={International Journal of Engineering Science},
  volume={2},
  number={2},
  pages={205--217},
  year={1964},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{eringen1966theory,
  title={Theory of micropolar fluids},
  author={Eringen, A Cemal},
  journal={Journal of Mathematics and Mechanics},
  pages={1--18},
  year={1966},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{peddieson1970recent,
  title={Recent Adv},
  author={Peddieson Jr, J and McNitt, R},
  journal={Eng. Sci},
  volume={5},
  pages={405},
  year={1970}
}

@article{hartmann1937hg,
  title={Hg-dynamics II},
  author={Hartmann, J and Lazarus, F},
  journal={Theory of laminar flow of electrically conductive Liquids in a Homogeneous Magnetic Field},
  volume={15},
  number={7},
  year={1937}
}

@article{pavlov1974magnetohydrodynamic,
  title={Magnetohydrodynamic flow of an incompressible viscous fluid caused by deformation of a plane surface},
  author={Pavlov, KB},
  journal={Magnitnaya Gidrodinamika},
  volume={4},
  number={1},
  pages={146--147},
  year={1974}
}
```

Comment: A friendly reminder: In order to pretty-print LaTeX or BibTeX code, just highlight the lines in question and click on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the editing window.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "type only references separately".

Comment: Provided that you want a document, that just includes all the references in a bib file, using `\nocite{*}` should work. Here is a MWE for bibtex: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\end{document}`

Comment: @leandriis Its work Great so simple. Thanks a lot for support. Thanks everyone

Comment: @leandriis an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you want a document, that just includes all the references in a bib file, using `\nocite{*}` should work. Here is a MWE for bibtex:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
\nocite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib} 
\end{document}
```

In combination with your `.bib` file, this results in the following output:

[image]

---

Depending on the expected order of the references, you might want to chose a different  `bibliographystyle`. While `plain` sorts the references based on the last name of the author, using `unsrt` would result in the references being listed in the same order in which they are cited, which in this specific case is identical to the order in which they appear in the `.bib` file.